# Swift Firestore Resultについて

Tags: swift, firebase

Firestoreのドキュメントの中で以下のようなエラー処理について悩んでいます。
参考https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data?hl=ja

```
let docRef = db.collection("cities").document("BJ")

docRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
    // Construct a Result type to encapsulate deserialization errors or
    // successful deserialization. Note that if there is no error thrown
    // the value may still be `nil`, indicating a successful deserialization
    // of a value that does not exist.
    //
    // There are thus three cases to handle, which Swift lets us describe
    // nicely with built-in Result types:
    //
    //      Result
    //        /\
    //   Error  Optional<City>
    //               /\
    //            Nil  City
    let result = Result {
      try document?.data(as: City.self)
    }
    switch result {
    case .success(let city):
        if let city = city {
            // A `City` value was successfully initialized from the DocumentSnapshot.
            print("City: \(city)")
        } else {
            // A nil value was successfully initialized from the DocumentSnapshot,
            // or the DocumentSnapshot was nil.
            print("Document does not exist")
        }
    case .failure(let error):
        // A `City` value could not be initialized from the DocumentSnapshot.
        print("Error decoding city: \(error)")
    }
}
```

この上記の中で、Resultというのはどこから来たのでしょうか？
また、このResultをletでoptionalにしている理由が分かりません。

私が思うには、引数としてのdocumentに対してresultの処理をすれば分かるのですが
成功した値であるdocumentとは別に、Resultを使っている理由が分かりません。
他のコードを見ると、成功したとしてdocumentを使っているからです。

ご教授よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

> Resultというのはどこから来たのでしょうか？

`Result`と言うのは、Swift標準ライブラリに含まれる型です。
[Result](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/result)

従来のように2つの変数を使って、「成功の場合は`result`に非nilの値を返し、`error`に`nil`を入れる。失敗の場合は`result`に`nil`を入れ、`error`に非nilの値を入れる」と言ったお約束では、`result`と`error`が両方nilになることはありえないことをSwiftの型システム上は表現できないので、そのような場面で使われることを想定しています。

`Result`の後ろにクロージャーが続いているのは、次のイニシャライザを使っています。

[init(catching:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/result/3139399-init)

このイニシャライザでは、クロージャーの中で`Error`が投げられた時に、`Result.failure(...)`を、エラー終了せずに戻り値が返された時に`Result.success(...)`を生成するようになっています。

---

> このResultをletでoptionalにしている理由が分かりません。

ご掲載のコードで`let`は複数箇所に現れているので、どの部分を言っているのか明確にされると、より的確な回答を得やすくなると思います。

ここでは、`case .success(let city)`の部分だと仮定しています。

ここでテストしているのは、`try document?.data(as: City.self)`が`Error`を投げたかどうかです。`document`はOptionalなので、`nil`であれば`data(as:)`メソッドが呼ばれないまま結果は`nil`になりますから、`try document?.data(as: City.self)`が成功時エラーを投げずに戻す値は`City`型ではなく、`Optional<City>`型になります。

---

> 成功した値であるdocumentとは別に、Resultを使っている理由が分かりません。

これは元のコードが著しく見にくい(天下のGoogleが発表しているコードだから良い書き方をしている、なんて思わない方が良い例ですね)せいもありますが、「何の成功・失敗」をどこで判定しているのかが十分伝わっていないようです。

- `getDocument`の成功・失敗

  成功: `document`が非nil, `error`が`nil`
  失敗: `document`が`nil`, `error` が非nil
- `data(as:)`の成功・失敗

  成功: `result`の値が`.success(City?)`
  失敗: `result`の値が`.failure(Error)`

  ※この場合の「成功」には`document`が`nil`のせいで`data(as:)`が呼ばれない場合を含む

つまり掲載されたコードは`getDocument`自体が失敗して、`document`には`nil`が入っている場合を後からチェックしていることになります。

---

少なくとも、どこでどんなエラーが発生しているのかチェックしていることをコードでわかりやすく表現したいなら、ご掲載のコードは及第点とは言えないですね。

例えばこんな風に書くともう少しわかりやすくなるでしょうか。

```
        let docRef = db.collection("cities").document("BJ")

        docRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print(error)
                return
            }
            guard let document = document else {
                print("Document does not exist")
                return
            }
            do {
                let city = try document.data(as: City.self)
                print("City: \(city)")
            } catch {
                print("Error decoding city: \(error)")
            }
        }
```

Comment: 大変分かりやすいコメント有難うございます。
ご教授して頂いた内容を元に、勉強させて頂きます。

Answer (score 0):

通常であれば、データがなければnilあれば失敗、データがあれば成功でもいい時はありますが、おそらく通信に失敗した、Cityにデコード失敗などのことを考慮するために、Resultを使用しているんだと思います。

Result自体は、Swift標準の機能で、try-catchと同じような例外処理の1つです。